# RactiveJS and preventDefault on toggle

Tags: mustache, ractivejs

The template contains:

```
<a href="#container" on-click="toggle('container')">Container</a>
<div id="container" class="{{ container ? '' : 'hide' }}"></div>
```

[...]

```
{{#each something:i}}
<a href="#example_{{@key}}" on-click="toggle('innerContainer.' + i)">Inner Container</a>
<div id="example_{{@key}}" class="{{ innerContainer[i] ? '' : 'hide' }}"></div>
{{/each}}
```

The *data* object is:

```
data = {
    something: {},
    container: true,
    innerContainer: []
};
```

and then JavaScript:

```
ractive.on('toggle', function (event) {
    event.original.preventDefault();
});
```

However, I can't find the way to use `preventDefault` method there as the `toggle` event handler is not called.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Handling events can be a bit confusing because there are two distinct styles:

1. Providing an event name to fire, e.g. `on-click="toggle"`
2. Providing a method call that applied to the current ractive instance: `on-click="toggle()"`

You can pass parameters to the event name style (`on-click="toggle:container"), but that is going to be deprecated so you may want to go with the slightly longer`on-click="fire('toggle', 'container')" if you need events.

In your example, I'm assuming you're trying to use Ractive existing `toggle` method, but just call prevent default on the event.

So one option would be to use:

```
new Ractive({
    // ...
    toggle( keypath ){
        _super( keypath );
        this.event.original.preventDefault();
    },
    // ...
});
```

The other would look like:

```
// on-click="fire('toggle', 'container')"

new Ractive({
    // ...
    oninit( keypath ){
        this.on( 'toggle', keypath => {
           this.toggle( keypath );
           this.event.original.preventDefault();
        });
    },
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I've tried second approach, but the object `this.event` contains only two properties: `_noArg: true, name: "toggle"`. There is no `original` property there. I could use global `event`, but that's sort of workaround.

And yes - I use Ractive existing `toggle` method.

Comment: I've done different approach with `on-click="customToggle(event, 'container')"` and then this works as the `event` now has property `original` and `keypath` `container`. Later I can use `event.original.preventDefault();` and `this.toggle(keypath);`

Comment: yes, you can pass in event object. you can also pass in `event.original`. You can also `return false;` but that may be broken in `0.7`